# Raspberry Pi 3 and RPLCD Library Not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to interface my raspberry pi with an LCD screen, however, I can not get the python library installed.
[Error Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w14T6.png)

Whenever I try to use pip/pip3 I get the same warning. Whenever I try python3-xyz, I get "can not find" and when I used pipx, I was able to get it installed and I could see that RPLCD was installed, but when I ran my program with "from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD", I get an error saying that RPLCD does not exist.

My pi and its python3 libraries are all up to date.

Any suggestions?